# Downsides of having a model with too many independent variables (factors)?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

It is often tempting in experimental design to make distinctions of all sorts in the manipulated variables, and thus to end up with a lot of factors in one's model (e.g. a 3x2x2x2x2 ANOVA).  The same holds (I think) for covarying for many extraneous variables, as in ANCOVA.

If I understand correctly, the reason why this is not recommended is because it decreases statistical power by decreasing the degrees of freedom of statistical (e.g. F-) tests. Is this true, and is there any other reason why it is desirable to minimise the number of factors (independent variables) in one's design?

Also, is there a way to quantitatively assess exactly how much power is lost by adding each factor, such that an experimenter can decide where to situate themselves in this trade-off and whether it is worth it or not including a certain factor in the model?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two other problems:

1) Parsimony.  Many people view parsimonious models as superior to less parsimonious ones, other things being equal.  This goes back to Ockham's razor.  However, there's always the question of just how parsimonious a model should be.

2) Overfitting. E.g in a 3x2x2x2x2 ANOVA there are 48 cells to estimate. Is there enough data?  In the extreme, if there is 1 observation in each cell, you can estimate them perfectly with noise.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this is helpful. Am I correct then to say that there is no hard&fast rule as to how many factors it is acceptable to have, or rather as to exactly how much power is lost for each factor added?

Comment: There is a general rule of thumb in regression to have 10 cases for each independent variable.

Comment: So for the 3x2x2x2x2 ANOVA, I guess this would translate to a total of 480 observations (10 per each cell of the design)? I'm a bit confused though about the within-/between-subjects nature of these observations, i.e. how many of them can come from repeated measures in a single subject as opposed to from several subjects?